Always allow comments on own answers?
Apologies if this is a dupe, on my phone and hard to search thoroughly. I understand the rationale for disallowing comments on general answers when rep <50, but I think users should always be able to comment on their own answers in response to other commenters, especially including OPs, even if rep<50. Can a change be made to allow comments on this case regardless of reputation?

Lookin at "comments" in our helpcenter it looks like you already should have this right. If it doesn't work, then either somehow the system doesn't get that you are the same person (i.e. different accounts), or there is a new bug. (Unfortunately I can't test this now.)

This is already the case. Regardless of reputation, you can always comment on your own posts, and on answers to your own questions.
